# If $A \subseteq B$, does this imply that there exists a function $f: A \to B$ such that $f$ is an injection?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove another problem that involves Schröeder-Bernstein, but I need to prove this beforehand. Does Schröeder-Bernstein imply this, already?

Comment: Yes: the *canonical  injection*, mapping each element of $A$ to itself as an element of $B$.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I already edited the question

Comment: Why wouldn't the identity function $f : A \to A \subset B$, prove to be an injection? (If you need a proof: Note that $f(a) =a \in A \subset B$ is clear. If $f(a) = f(b)$, then by definition  of $f$,  $a=b$. Hence, $f$ is an injection). If this does not work, I request you to point out to me, where is the mistake in the proof, because I know that while working with finely threaded set theoretic axioms, I may have assumed something I am not allowed to (or have not proved).

Comment: You can simply take the function prescribed by $x\mapsto x$ for $x\in A\subseteq B$.

Comment: Since the identity function is injective, can I say that there exists not only an injection, but also a bijection between sets $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 1):

The Cantor–Bernstein theorem only tells you that **if** there are injections $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to A$, then there is a bijection $h\colon A\to B$.

Commonly, we can somewhat reduce the proof to the case where $f\colon B\to A$ is injective and $A\subseteq B$. This is because, as noted in the comments, $g(x)=x$ is an injection from $A$ into $B$.

But this has nothing to do with the actual theorem.

Comment: So I only have to proof that at least one function exists right? It doesn't matter which one, and in this case the identity function is always injective from $A$ to $A$ which is a subset of $B$.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to prove. But I'd guess the answer is no.

Comment: I am sorry, I keep assuming that I wrote things I did not. So, to use Schroeder Bernstein, it does not matter what is the injection I find, as long as I find one (or two for the case from the second set to the first).

Comment: If you want to use the Cantor--Bernstein theorem, you need to have two injections between $A$ and $B$. In the case where $A$ is a subset of $B$, then there is an obvious injection from $A$ to $B$, so you only need to find an injection from $B$ into $A$ in order to appeal to the theorem. If that what you meant, then yes.

Comment: I am trying to prove that if $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ and the cardinality of $A$ is the same as that of $C$ then the cardinality of $A$ is the same as that of $B$. I am trying to get an injection from $B$ to $A$, or $C$ to $B$, but I can't find one.